# How can I remove the delay of a QML ToolTip?

Tags: user-interface, frontend, qml, qqmlcomponent

I rebuilt a periodic table using QML and stumbled upon the following problem. Due to size limitations I decided to reduce the amount of information that is shown to a minimum and instead implemented the option to hover over a certain element which causes a tooltip to show up, offering more information.

[Periodic table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsMH5.png)

[tooltip with more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCJ9h.png)

My problem is, that when you move the cursor to take a look at a different element, the tooltip will not stop showing immediately but slowly fade out instead. Rambling from side to side with your mouse will show this for example:

[delayed tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqbTR.png)

Is there a way to remove this fadeout and let the tooltips disappear immediately instead? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I should have probably mentioned this beforehand, but I have already tried setting this property. Unfortunately it has nothing to do with the fading effect, it only sets the timespan in which the tooltip is being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined in the style you are using. Either you write your own style, a custom `ToolTip` or overwrite manually every time. To fix it you need to overwrite the [exit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#exit-prop) transition.

```
Button {
    id: button
    text: qsTr("Save")

    ToolTip {
        parent: button
        visible: button.hovered
        delay: 500
        text: "This is a ToolTip"
        exit: Transition {}
    }
}
```